# Normal Distribution - percentiles

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

i have this closed question,
I don't know how to solve it, I have only the answer but I would like to understand the solution and know how to solve them,
Thank you!

1.From a population that is normally distributed in which the 44th percentile is 44, a sample of 44 participants is taken. The probability that the sample's average will be higher than 44 is:

1. 28%
2. 51%
3. 56%
4. 84% (The right answer)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The question doesn't state the mean or the standard deviation of the population, so these two variables will vary together. Using some experimentation, I found that a normal distribution with mean $50$ with a 44th percentile of 44 has a standard deviation of about 40. Then the probability that a sample of size 44 will have an average greater than 44 is given by $P\left(Z>\frac{44-50}{40/\sqrt{44}}\right)\approx 0.84012882$. Seeing as there are infinitely many distributions that satisfy the criterion given in the problem, I tried a normal distribution with mean $10^9$ having standard deviation $6.7*10^9$ with a 44th percentile still at 44. The probability that your sample mean from a sample of size 44 is greater than 44 is still about $0.838922$. So the normal distribution's percentiles are very robust.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say $X$ is a member of the population which is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, neither of which are known.  But we know
$$P(X < 44) = 0.44$$
and $$X < 44 \iff \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} < \frac{44-\mu}{\sigma}$$

and $(X-\mu)/\sigma$ has a Normal(0,1) distribution, so we know from tables of the distribution that
$$\frac{44-\mu}{\sigma} = -0.151$$
The average of the sample of size $44$, $\bar{X}$, has a mean of $\mu$ and a standard deviation of $\sigma / \sqrt{44}$.  Now
$$\bar{X} > 44 \iff \frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sigma / \sqrt{44}} > \left( \frac{44-\mu}{\sigma} \right) \sqrt{44}=-0.151 \sqrt{44} = -1.00$$
so $P(\bar{X} > 44) = P(Z> -1.00)$, where $Z$ has a Normal(0,1) distribution.  Refering to a table of the Normal distribution, we have
$$P(\bar{X} > 44) = \boxed{0.84}$$